# PInvoking with StringBuilder in a Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, c, unit-testing, pinvoke

I have a C DLL I am PInvoking. The main goal is to get back a GUID string of 39 characters, such as `abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd`.

I first call one method to get the size of this string, which I expect to be 39 characters, and then I call another function passing it a `StringBuilder` with a capacity of 39:

```
[DllImport("test.dll")]
public static extern int get_size();

[DllImport("test.dll")]
public static extern void get_string(StringBuilder result);
```

My code looks something like this:

```
int size = get_size(); // Returns 40, because it includes the null terminating character.
var result = new StringBuilder(size - 1); // Gives it a capacity of 39. Subtracting 1 here because this does not fancy that null terminator over the marshaling layer.
get_string(result);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

When I call this in a console application, I get back this result: `abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd`

When I call this from a unit test with the exact same code, I get back this result: `abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdq`

Note the `q` on the end, the extra character that is added, and that from debugging the unit test I can verify that the capacity of the `StringBuilder` object has increased significantly up to 42 **after** the call to `get_string` despite being initialized with a capacity of 39. Why is this happening? Is this normal? Am I doing something wrong? Why only in the unit tests?

The C implementation is something like this:

```
static char *_result = NULL; // At some point result is initialized and set.

int get_size() {
    if (_result != NULL)
        return strlen(_result) + 1;
    return 1;
}

void get_string(char *result) {
    if (result != NULL && _result != NULL)
        strncpy(result, _result, strlen(_result));
}
```

Comment: maybe the C implementation of these functions might shed some light. Could you add it?

Comment: @FelixPalmen  One moment, I will add it in.

Comment: Don't know the answer to that question but, Have you tried not giving a size at all?

Comment: @jambodev this wouldn't work, passing a `StringBuilder` with P/Invoke gives the "unmanaged" code a pointer to the builder's internal buffer. It will just write there without the `StringBuilder` noticing. So, it shouldn't even be possible that the capacity changes when calling the C function, still I'm curious to see this code as well ...

Comment: nothing special apart from the buffer not being touched at all if `_result` happens to be still `NULL`. @Alexandru this couldn't be the culprit, could it?

Comment: It doesn't fix your problem, but your `get_string()` uses for `strncpy()` as length parameter the length of the source string. Instead it should use the available length of the destination. But that would mean you had to change the signature to `get_string(char* result, int length)`.

Comment: @jambodev I just tried, but like Felix said, this returns `abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdXXXXXXXX`, it fills it with a bunch of extra characters.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Oh, you might be right. Perhaps the buffer is `NULL` in some instances, causing some weird results...I need to play around with this a bit more...

Comment: @Oliver Actually, I think your suggestion will solve my problem! Because then, I can memset the buffer to be null, and then fill it as needed thereafter.

Comment: Another remark: I think subtracting one is wrong, because marhalling happens **after** your native code wrote to the buffer. So the buffer must have the room for the `'\0'` available.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I think you might be right.

Comment: Thanks guys, some great feedback, I fixed it and will post the overall solution below! This is good stuff, hopefully it helps those in the same situation.

Comment: Full fix below! Thanks a bunch, everyone!

Comment: You know, its funny that it was even updating the buffer at all to begin with, because it went past the null check on the buffer, so StringBuilder must be allocating a random buffer space for the native world and not memory setting it to 0 at all. Something to be mindful of. :)

Comment: @Alexandru I'm not sure about this, maybe the native function wrote happily beyond the bounds of the `StringBuilder`s buffer, overwriting some other internal metadata (like the buffer size) and somehow, magically, this didn't crash ;) With *managed code*, whatever you write is defined and exceptions will be thrown at you if necessary, but bring native code to the table and say hello to infamous **undefined behavior** ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Indeed, and what matters most is that we put our heads together and came up with a solid fix. This is why I love StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This required a few fixes.

The function signature needed to change:

```
[DllImport("test.dll")]
public static extern int get_size();

[DllImport("test.dll")]
public static extern void get_string(int resultSize, StringBuilder result);
```

The C implementation needed to change:

```
static char *_result = NULL; // At some point result is initialized and set.

int get_size() {
    if (_result != NULL)
        return strlen(_result) + 1;
    return 1;
}

void get_string(int resultSize, char *result) {
    memset(result, 0, resultSize);
    if (_result != NULL)
        strncpy(result, _result, resultSize);
}
```

The C# call needed to change:

```
int resultSize = get_size();
var result = new StringBuilder(resultSize); // Needed to also include the null Terminator ("I'LL BE BACK" - ARNOLD).
get_string(resultSize, result);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

A note to rookies of C...if you're not using `char`, and you're using something like `wchar_t` or otherwise, along with your string length calculation methods, you'll need to multiply your buffer sizes by `sizeof(wchar_t)` instead when doing operations like `memset`, since there's a big difference between number of characters in a string and number of bytes in a string. I just happen to know what `sizeof(char)` is 1 so I've omitted this from the implementation to save code.